# Printing with my custom fonts is not working

Tags: html, css, printing

I created a webpage with the custom font, I can see the fonts applied in the browser but its not applied in the printed page.

I followed the below way for printing :

The fonttest.css file contains the following content :

```
@font-face {
font-family: "myriad";
src: url("../fonts/myriad.otf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
font-family: "serifa-bold";
src: url("../fonts/serifa_bold.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
font-family: "serifa";
src: url("../fonts/serifa.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
font-family: "AlexandriaFLF";
src: url("../fonts/AlexandriaFLF.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
font-family: "AlexandriaFLF-Bold";
src: url("../fonts/AlexandriaFLF-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
font-family: "AlexandriaFLF-BoldItalic";
src: url("../fonts/AlexandriaFLF-BoldItalic.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
font-family: "AlexandriaFLF-Italic";
src: url("../fonts/AlexandriaFLF-Italic.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

In the HTML file the CSS file is linked as below :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all'  href='resource/css/fonttest.css' />
```

I was printing the following below lines :

```
<p style="font-family:myriad;color:#000000">myriad-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</p>
<p style="font-family:serifa-bold;color:#000000">serifa-bold-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</p>
<p style="font-family:serifa;color:#000000">serifa-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</p>
<p style="font-family:AlexandriaFLF;color:#000000">AlexandriaFLF-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</p>
<p style="font-family:AlexandriaFLF-Italic;color:#000000">AlexandriaFLF-Italic-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</p>
<p style="font-family:AlexandriaFLF-Bold;color:#000000">AlexandriaFLF-Bold-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</p>
<p style="font-family:AlexandriaFLF-BoldItalic;color:#000000">AlexandriaFLF-BoldItalic-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</p>
```

please help me ?

Comment: Can you post the URL of a demo page and identify the browser(s) you used for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the url https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=468568 which explains why print is not working for custom fonts, so I tested in `firefox-20.0a1.en-US.win32.installer.exe`. The fonts with ttf and otf are applied exactly as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your stylesheet media attribute to print :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='print'  href='resource/css/fonttest.css' />
```

Comment: `media='all'`, which is present in the question, should include print.

Comment: I have a doubt about being able to print using fontFace ? try to set another safe font and see if it works. If so, then font-face can't be printed. I think it should be installed on the user system first. I think, i'm not sure, but give it a try.

Comment: My Firefox version is : 12.0, and My Safari Version is :5.1.2, I tried with below test cases: **Case 1** : `Tested with one otf file, and multiple ttf fonts in my css, I can see only the otf is applied in firefox, but in safari the otf font applied text is ok but the ttf font applied text is jumbled text` **Case 2** : `Tested with two otf files, multiple ttf files, in safari all the otf font text is applied properly and again the ttf font text is jumbled and in firefox the previously applied otf is applied for the whole text`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find a way to do this, there is an alternative.

You could use [wkhtml2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) and make a printable PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you may need to include more fonts formats in your css.
Something like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'XXXXX';
src: url('XXXXX.eot');
src: url('XXXXX.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('XXXXX.woff') format('woff'),
     url('XXXXX.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('XXXXX.svg#XXXXX') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
printWindow.document.write(`
      <html>
  <head>
    <title>Print</title>
    <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
      src: url("path-to-custom-font") format("opentype");
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
      src:url('path-to-custom-font') format("opentype");
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
      src:url('path-to-custom-font') format("opentype");
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
      src:url('path-to-custom-font') format("opentype");
      font-weight: 700;
    }

      @media print {
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
          src: url("path-to-custom-font") format("opentype");
          font-weight: 300;
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
          src:url('path-to-custom-font') format("opentype");
          font-weight: 400;
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
          src:url('path-to-custom-font') format("opentype");
          font-weight: 500;
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
          src:url('path-to-custom-font') format("opentype");
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        
        body {
          font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
        }
      }

      body {
        font-family: 'Founders Grotesk', sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${content-you-want-to-send-in-print-file}</body>
  </html>`);
printWindow.document.close();
setTimeout(() => {
  printWindow.print();
  printWindow.close();
}, 5000);
```

For me it work when I specified the custom font in separate style as well as wrap them in print media stylesheet. So when you write code for print function try this way. Here I have also add delay for font-family to load.